# Let Σ = Ø. How many different languages can be defined on Σ?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Here is the question: 
Let Σ = Ø. How many different languages can be defined on Σ?

Comment: How many can you think of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's exactly one language over the empty alphabet. Its only word is the empty word $\varepsilon$.